# Perform three different action for a single button

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I want to perform three different actions for a single button. I surfed in google also it shows some different options but those are not helpful.

I have declared NSInteger inside CustomUIButton i.e. click and initialize inside IBAction to 0.
Here is the code.

```
-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender
{
    CustomUIButton *button=sender;
    NSInteger flag = 0;
    button.click=0;
    if(button.click==0)
    {
        button.click=1;
        [button setSelected:NO];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=0;
    }
    else if (button.click==1)
    {
        button.click=2;
        [button setSelected:YES];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Present_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=1;
    }
    else if (button.click==3)
    {
        button.click=0;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Late_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setSelected:YES];
        flag=3;
    }

}
```

But it is not working. Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: But I want to show those three different images on three times button click. Can it be possible?

Comment: Are you want to create like animation.

Comment: button.click=0; define this somewhere outside this button function . every time you click it assign button.click=0; every times its zero for initialise it some where else

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ya I want like that for every click it should be change and at last it should when it will show Late_on_coloured.png after that if I will click again it will show again Absent_on_coloured.png.

Comment: Okay correct me if I am wrong. when you click for first time image will change to Absent_on_coloured.png, second time it will change to Present_on_coloured.png third time it will change to Late_on_coloured.png again it will start from Absent_on_coloured.png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `button.click=0;` globally so initially its value will be zero and after that it will increase.

```
@interface yourclass : superclass
{
   int click;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad{

      click=0;

}

-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender
{
CustomUIButton *button=sender;
NSInteger flag = 0;

if(click==0)
{
    click=1;
    [button setSelected:NO];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag=0;
}
else if (button.click==1)
{
    click=2;
    [button setSelected:YES];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Present_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag=1;
}
else if (button.click==3)
{
    click=0;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Late_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    flag=3;
}

}
```

Comment: Actually my button is not in storyboard I have created it using CustomUIButton in different method. Then how can I set the value of  button.click in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: create a global variable instead of button click. I have updated the answer check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the button.click = 0 for every action.
So every time you click it is being set to zero. 
You can instead keep a separate variable to count in your view controller than having a click property on button. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Can you Please write in code what exactly you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code,
it was always goes on

```
if(button.click==0)
{
button.click=1;
[button setSelected:NO];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
flag=0;
}
```

I will give you better suggestion instead of "click" you can use "tag" option which was the one property of uibutton.
First you have to define a custom button on .h file and then set the tag = 0 in `- (void)viewDidLoad`
 method.

Comment: Actually my button is not in storyboard I have created it using CustomUIButton in different method. Then how can I set the value of tag=0 in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: every control have a tag property. when you create button using CustomUIButton like  CustomUIButton * custButton = [[CustomUIButton alloc]init]; after that you have set custButton.tag = 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomUIButton *button;
        NSInteger flag = 0;
        button.click=0;
```

use it this way or as simple from all such problems use some other variable as 
because every time this function is call its zero every time so make it outside this function and use it

```
  NSInteger flag = 0;
  int counter = 0;
-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender
    {

    if(counter ==0)
    {
        counter =1;
        [button setSelected:NO];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=0;
    }
    else if (counter ==1)
    {
        counter =2;
        [button setSelected:YES];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Present_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=1;
    }
    else if (counter ==3)
    {
        counter =0;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Late_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setSelected:YES];
        flag=3;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in start button tag to zero then change as following

```
-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender{
     CustomUIButton *button=sender;
     NSInteger flag = 0;
     if(button.tag==0)
     {
         button.tag=1;
     }     
     else if (button.tag==1)
     {
        button.tag=2;
     }
     else if (button.click==3)
     {
          button.tag=0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code may be solve your problem.

```
-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender
{
    CustomUIButton *button=sender;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
       [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Present_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Late_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```